# typescript TS1005 error when importing types from type definition

Tags: typescript

One of the libraries (`parse5`) used by my project is exposing typing information (in .d.ts files) using the following syntax to import types:

```
import { type CharacterToken, type DoctypeToken, type TagToken, type EOFToken, type CommentToken } from '../common/token.js';
```

This is causing a bunch of typescript errors when running the application, since it looks like typescript doesn't recognise this why of importing types.

If I change the syntax to

```
import type { CharacterToken, DoctypeToken, TagToken, EOFToken, CommentToken } from '../common/token.js';
```

I don't get any error.

might it be that I'm using a wrong tsc version?

Comment: Have you exported `type` from a `.js` file?

Comment: @Jai That's the transpiled version the one you find in node_modules folder. I mentioned it's a library. So, the source file it's a TS file which then gets transpiled to .js file and the .d.ts type definition file is then created. I don't have any control over it since it's an external library

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript(3.8) you should use `import type { SomeThing } from "./some-module.js";`, not `import { type SomeThing } from "./some-module.js";`

[More info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax used in the 'parse5' package for importing types was introduced with Typescript 4.5: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#type-modifiers-on-import-names

I ran into the same problem on a project using typescript 4.4, and **upgrading to 4.5** resolved the issue for me.

Checking the open issues on parse5 revealed that many people have the same problem, e.g. look at https://github.com/inikulin/parse5/issues/913#issuecomment-1520222908